# unrecognized selector sent to instance ... was thrown while invoking on target with params

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm using a library in my react-native project where I'm getting this error [image]

Below is one of the function in the Implementation file of the ios folder of library I'm using. I'm getting error on calling the below function.
Also, I'm getting this error since I updated to Xcode 14.1 (and iOS 16.1), with react-native (0.66.4)

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCardToken:(NSString *)cardNumber expirationDate:(NSString *)expirationDate CVV:(NSString *)CVV resolve: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    BMSCardInfo *card = [BMSCardInfo new];
    card.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    card.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    card.CVV = CVV;

    [[BMSAPI instance] generateAccountForCard:card completion:^(BMSAccount *account, NSError *error){
        if (account) {
            resolve(account.token);
        } else {
            reject(@"error", error.localizedDescription, error);
        }
    }];
}
```